# selecting a document with filtered values of embedded documents

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation

can you guide me as to how i can make C# equivalent

```
db.UserProfile.aggregate([
    {$match:{_id:"sen"}},  
    {
          $project: {
             DemRole: {
                $filter: {
                   input: "$DemRole",
                   as: "item",
                   cond: { $eq: [ "$$item.Name", "CO" ] }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    ])
```

I am trying to select a document if matches _id and retrieve the result after applying filter on embedded documents.It works fine in MongoDB on Robo3T. But i m not able to translate the same in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
var collection = new MongoClient().GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<User>("UserProfile");
var pipeline = collection.Aggregate()
                         .Match(up => up.Id == "sen")
                         .Project(up => new { DemRole = up.DemRole.Where(c => c.Name == "CO") });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. It works in C# now. But Below is how i could get the information.

```
 var pipeline = collection.Aggregate()
                         .Match(up => up.UserID == userId)
                         .Project(up => new { DemRole = up.DemRole.Where(c => c.Status== true) }).ToList();
              // .Project(dem => dem.DemRole.Where(c => c.Status == true));//.ToList();


        foreach(var pipe in pipeline)
        {
            return pipe.DemRole.ToList();

        }
```

I would like to know the operation the below code  performs

```
.Project(up => new { DemRole = up.DemRole.Where(c => c.Status== true) })
```

and why below code does not work.

```
  .Project(dem => dem.DemRole.Where(c => c.Status == true));//.ToList();
```

Moreover i had to run a foreach to get the information as given below.

```
foreach(var pipe in pipeline)
        {
            return pipe.DemRole.ToList();

        }
```

If you could explain the above lines or point me to some documentation which i can go through,it would be better.